# one user has two roles, need to redirect to /admin, but redirects to /user

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I added two roles(ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER) for one user and after succesful login I need it to redirect to /admin form, but keep getting /user form.

I tried adding RoleHierarchy, but result stays the same.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .expressionHandler(expressionHandler())
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**")
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user")
                .hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .successHandler(successUserHandler)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }
@Component
public class SuccessUserHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                        Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils
                .authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_USER")) {
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/user");
        } else if(roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")){
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/admin");
        } else {
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your IF statement you first have a check if it is a user. Assuming your admin has also the user role hat is the first match and you'll be always redirected to /user

Comment: didn't thought about this moment, thanks a lot!!